# TensorFlow Android Camera Demo - classify grayscale images

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-vision

I have trained my own neural network on grayscale images and now I want to plug it in to the classifier from TensorFlow Android Camera Demo (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android).

How can I modify ClassifierActivity.java (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java) so that I pass a grayscale input image to my computation graph?

I will need to do something with bitmaps, I am just not quite sure what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for you to edit your TensorFlow graph so that you do the grayscale conversion in TensorFlow. It will be faster and easier than doing this on Android. This is the rgb to grayscale conversion in TensorFlow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale
And the way to do it is to add this to your graph before you freeze the graph to put it on the android device. I have tried this on Android and it works.